# How many options of each part in GoogleForm?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

I have a Google Form with Multiple-choice questions only.
I want to count the number of options of each question in it by python + selenium.
How can i do that ?
Please help me!

```
import time
import random
from selenium import webdriver

#driver
chromeDriver = "D:/AppMadeByMe/googleform/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromeDriver)

linkForm = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSc_aGBHkJfoDMxX9cy1wU9lV2bWsdcIx3m05jT64XYNNu24cw/viewform'
driver.get(linkForm)

#Xpath - get the unchange part's XPATH
xpRigth = '//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div['
xpMid = ']/div[2]/div/content/div/label['
xpLeft = ']/div/div[1]/div[3]/div'
xpSubmit = '//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/content/span'
xpResubmit = '/html/body/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/a'

#count number of questions

optionmaxNum = [3,4,3,4,2] #number answers of each questions
num_ans = []

lenOption = len(optionmaxNum)
count = 0
while(count < 100):
    count += 1
    for i in range(0,lenOption):
        num_ans.append(random.randint(1,optionmaxNum[i]))
    for i in range(1,lenOption+1):
        xp = xpRigth + str(i) + xpMid + str(num_ans[i-1]) + xpLeft
        d = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xp)
        d.click()
        time.sleep(0.1)
    num_ans = []
    submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpSubmit)

    submit.click()
    time.sleep(0.5)

    resub = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpResubmit)
    resub.click()
```

Comment: See [ask]. What have you tried? What research have you done? Question work best here if you show some code that illustrates the problem.

Comment: this is the first time i use Stackoverflow.
I am writing an autofil GoogleForm bot with python and selenium, but i have to count the numbers of options of each question manually.
and i am stuck when i try to count automatically :((

Comment: You might want to take the [tour] then. The idea is that you ask specific questions about code you have written. Tell us what you want to do, show what you have tried, and tell us what result you get.

Comment: I am writing an autofil GoogleForm bot with python and selenium, but i have to count the numbers of options of each question manually. and i am stuck when i try to count automatically

Comment: i have edited my question! <3

Comment: @jdv Have you got any idea?